# Cloud Foundry: Error 402: App packaging failed: 'Application exceeds maximum allowed size (536.87MB)'

Tags: java, spring, cloud-foundry

My app is certainly large, but the 536MB limit seems strange given that my    `$ vmc stats` is setup like this:

```
+----------+-------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+
| Instance | CPU (Cores) | Memory (limit) | Disk (limit) | Uptime        |
+----------+-------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+
| 0        | 1.3% (4)    | 976.5M (2G)    | 263.0M (2G)  | 0d:0h:32m:56s |
+----------+-------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Does anyone know how to avoid the 402 Error?

Cheers,
Bryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual (default) limit for the "droplet size" (the total size of your app's source and resources) is 512MB; that turns out to be 536 * 10^6 bytes.

If you are running on cloudfoundry.com then that's it, you can't control that parameter, all you can do is reduce the size of your code.
However, I *think* this limit applies to the size before staging. This means that you can probably split some of the code out into Maven dependencies. Worth a try.

If you have your own installation however, you can fix this by editing cloud_controller.yml and changing the `max_droplet_size` parameter.
Note that the value is interpreted as bytes, do your math :)

Answer (score 0):

`max_droplet_size` has been changed to `max_package_size`. However, you may also have to change nginx's `client_max_body_size`.